# Show that $\Sigma=E(XX^T)-\mu\mu^T$.

Tags: random-variables, variance

Let $X\in \mathbb R^d$ be a random vector and $\mu=E(X)\in \mathbb R^d$ be its mean. Let $\Sigma=E[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^T]\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ be the variance-covariance matrix of X. Show that $\Sigma=E(XX^T)-\mu\mu^T$.

**Attempt**

Ok so I know if you have $(x-y)^T(x-y)=(x^T-y^T)(x-y)=x^Tx-2x^Ty+y^Ty$. So here I tried to do something similar. $\Sigma=E[(X-\mu)(X^T-\mu^T)]=E[XX^T-X\mu^T-\mu X^T+\mu\mu^T]=E[XX^T]-E[X\mu^T+\mu X^T]+\mu\mu^T$. There's an extra term there. Are these operations not valid for the outer product? Or what am I missing?

Comment: What is $E[AXB]$ if $A,B$ are constant matrices of appropriate dimensions?

Comment: Probably $AE(X)B$.

Comment: And what would $E[X]$ be just to finish things out?

Comment: Oh this problem again. Had this problem before. didn't notice that the addition has to be subtracted two terms from it. $E(X)=\mu$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is fine. By linearity of expectaion $EX\mu^{T}=\mu\mu^{T}$ and $E\mu^{T}X=\mu\mu^{T}$ so we get $\Sigma=EXX^{T}-\mu \mu^{T}$.